# API for list info of subscriptions, plans, recurring payments created by form with "_xclick-subscriptions"

Tags: paypal

What API I need to using for get data of subscriptions, plans, invoices,... created by form with "_xclick-subscriptions"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for historical information, or for information of new transactions?

If information of new transactions, webhooks will work. See https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/webhooks/

If you are looking for historical information of past transactions, see https://business.paypal.com/merchantdata/reportHome , particularly the Activity Download for CSV format files.  Do not use PayPal APIs to fetch historical data, they are not designed for this purpose and will either not work, will not return the necessary data, or will be very slow. Use the activity download.